# Do post-retirement earnings affect the amount of the benefit?

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan, social-security

Suppose Person A, who does not have a full 35 years of earnings, and was not a high earner, files for retirement benefits at age 62.  The benefits will be rather small.

What if Person A starts earning more -- after filing?  Will the retirement benefit be adjusted?  Or is it fixed at the time of filing?

Comment: @Lawrence - Thanks.  I've corrected the title now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SSA: Getting Benefits While Working](https://www.ssa.gov/planners/retire/whileworking.html)

> You can work while you receive Social Security retirement (or
>   survivors) benefits. When you do, it could mean a higher benefit for
>   you in the future.
>
> Each year we review the records for all working Social Security
>   recipients. If your earnings for the prior year are higher than one of
>   the years we used to compute your retirement benefit, we will
>   recalculate your benefit amount. We pay the increase retroactive to
>   January the year after you earned the money.
>
> Higher benefits can be important to you later in life and increase the
>   future benefit amounts your family and your survivors could receive.

Later on the page:

> Also, as long as you continue to work and receive benefits, we will
>   check your record every year to see whether the additional earnings
>   will increase your monthly benefit. If there is an increase, we will
>   send you a letter telling you of your new benefit amount.
>
> In addition, after you reach full retirement age, we will recalculate
>   your benefit amount to give you credit for any months in which you did
>   not receive a benefit because of your earnings. We will send you a
>   letter telling you about any increase in your benefit amount.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10069.pdf

> if you’re younger than full retirement age, and **earn more than certain amounts, your benefits will be reduced**.
>
> The amount that your benefits are reduced, however, **isn’t truly lost**. Your benefit will increase at your full retirement age to account for benefits withheld due to earlier earnings.
>
> If you’re younger than full retirement age, there is a limit to how
> much you can earn and still receive full Social Security benefits. If you’re younger than full retirement age during all of 2019, **we must deduct $1 from your benefits for each $2 you earn above $17,640**.

Comment: Also, once the person passes full retirement age, the benefits are no longer reduced, and if you earn more in a year than the adjusted 35 years, that will replace the lowest year, and the benefit amount increased accordingly.